# Symfony sonataadmin create a multichoices configureDatagridFilters datagridMapper

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

i want to create a multichoices choices in my function configureDatagridFilters, this is the code

```
$datagridMapper
            ->add('typeOffre',
                null,
                [
                    'show_filter' => true,
                ],
                'choice',
                array('choices' => [
                    'Profiter de l\'offre' => "profiter_offre",
                    'Brochure' => 'brochure',
                    'Essaie' => 'essaie',
                    'Contact' => 'contact',
                    'Demande de services' => 'demande_services',
                    'Informations' => 'informations',
                ],
                    'multiple' => true,
                )
            )
```

but when i submit the form i get this error:

Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

any solutions ??

**Edit with solution**

after a hours of debug, i found the solution, i used a query builder to filter a another select in my filter, but the where clause was expects parameter 1 to be string, array given, for this i used a foreach to fix this probleme, this is my code:

```
$siteSource = null;
$siteSource = $this->getRequest()->query->get('filter')['siteSource']['value'];
if($siteSource != null ){
foreach ($siteSource as $oneSite) {
 $er->orWhere('l.siteSource = :siteSource')->setParameter('siteSource', $oneSite);
   }
 }
```

Comment: If you found the solution, post it as answer and accept it. Don't edit the question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helps:

```
$datagridMapper->add('typeOffre', 'doctrine_orm_choice', array(
            'show_filter' => true), 'choice', array(
            'choices' => [
                'Profiter de l\'offre' => "profiter_offre",
                'Brochure' => 'brochure',
                'Essaie' => 'essaie',
                'Contact' => 'contact',
                'Demande de services' => 'demande_services',
                'Informations' => 'informations',
            ],   
            'multiple' => true));
```